# How create overflow menu on my navigation drawer toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm unable to create the overflow on my navigation drawer toolbar as I'm trying with the normal way of creating it which is crashing my app.

Here, I have created navigation drawer toolbar

```
 android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);

   toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
```

here are my menu items

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/Share_app"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title="Share App"
    android:icon="@drawable/share_app"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/Enquiry"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:title="Enquiry Form"
    android:icon="@drawable/enq_frm"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

here is my mainActivity toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="XYZ" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/Enquiry"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="Enquiry Form"
        android:icon="@drawable/enq_frm"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: thanks bro i tried with that but my app is not showing the overflow icon only and i'm not getting any error also the app is working fine

Comment: bro i tried but it not showing me the overflow icon i don't know what went wrong.